# How can I pass a stream from one thread to the other?May be I should be doing this differently?

Tags: java, multithreading, stream, outputstream, processbuilder

I have a wrapper for a `ProcessBuilder` so that any class needing to run a process can use it.
The class passes the process and the arguments and will return the result.
The result would be the outputstream of the `Process` or the errorstream I guess.
My question is how is the stream to be passed among threads? I mean I am doing something like the following:

```
String line=null;  
try {  
    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
            if (pw != null)  
                    pw.println(line);                   
        }
} catch (IOException e) {             
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
if (pw != null)  
       pw.flush();
```

I guess I should `flush` but not close the steam right? Or should I be doing it differently?

Comment: Are you trying to access the same stream simulataneously between multiple threads, or just handoff the stream for different threads to use at different times?  Also, have you come across [Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/)?  Its API is generally easier than `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: @hertzsprung.No.I want to pass the stream from the thread that is bind to the `InputStream` of the `Process` to the caller thread that initially wanted to run a process and `waitFor` the `process` to finish

Comment: Are you trying to determine who should be responsible for closing the streams ? In your current code you just read the stream data into a line and presumably pass that around. I assume that is not what you want ?

Comment: @DeepakBala:Well what I need is a way to pass these lines from inputstream of the process to the caller thread.Should I just copy the input stream to an outputstream and return the outputstream?Then who closes that stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the data to a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) and pass that to the caller. Once you are done writing to the BAOS close the inputstream and pass the outputstream to the caller. It is the caller's responsibility to close / flush the BAOS and release any memory associated with it.